# How to hide error dialog box in 7zip?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, zip, 7-zip

I am using `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" -y x -pmypassword "D:\Myfile.rar" -o"D:\Extracted Files\"` for extracting a file encrypted with password. Now if 'mypassword' is not the correct password 7zip brings an error-box saying 'Wrong Password?' I want to suppress this dialog-box.

`-inul` does the exact thing for `WinRar.exe`, it suppress error dialog-box from coming up and keeps executing the next lines. I want an equivalent command of `-inul` for `7zG.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

7-Zip writes all its messages to stdout, including error and warning messages. This means you can collect all the output from it by redirecting stdout it to a file.

A command like the following will redirect all output (including from stderr) to Log.txt:

`7za a Test.7z *.* >Log.txt 2>&1`